# define float as center in css

Tags: css, layout, html, alignment, css-float

How can I define a define float as center in css? actually i need a layout between right and left and also i tried "text-align" but it doesn't work and the "float" property just working.

Thank you

Comment: Both yopefonic and dcaunt's techniques are perfectly valid (despite dcaunt's comment). They both have their specific use cases and drawbacks.

Comment: Perhaps, but I think yopefonic's technique is obfuscated - developers should know how text-align works with the 0 auto margin to achieve centering - it's so often required. It's also easier to maintain if widths change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
<div style="width: 500px; text-align: center;">

    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100px;">I am centered</div>

</div>
```

The key is text-align: center on the parent, and a margin: 0 auto on the inner element

Comment: the most applicable and most common way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no float: center. but when you want a div to be centered to its parent this should do the trick:

```
#parent-element{
    position: relative;
}
#element
{
  width: 500px; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px; /* - (width/2)  */
  position: absolute;
}
```

but,  what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @dcaunt, I'd downvote your comment if I could. While this technique can lead to problems on small screens, sometimes it's exactly what's needed to solve a problem, especially with complex layered layouts. Yours is the more common solution, but yopefonic's isn't *wrong*.

Comment: What's the best use case for this over the text-align approach? My comment might have been overly harsh!

Comment: @dcaunt, no problem. I agree that it is not THE solution but as indicated the text-align was causing some problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can only float an element to the left or the right.

Maybe describe what kind of layout you are trying to achieve.